# Form doesn't update via hook in edit mode, instead of it page reloading

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, ajax

This is not happening all time (possibly for big amount of existing field, I'm not sure, with less amount of fields form is saving as it should) when I'm adding new Field collection entity or update existing field.

Using common role for this on save via button, which assign func with code to compare and save data using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, it just reload page without changes (ajax post request contains new fields values, but response on it return only previous version of page in html).

Using the admin role I'm instantly getting ajax warning with status 200

- Chrome says parsererror
- Firefox says OK, path: system/ajax, no text, in journal i have "Invalid form POST data", but my POST data definitely valid.

Watchdog logging show me that func for saving data isn't triggering, and after page reload it just reassign func to button via hook.

**Installation:**

- Drupal 7.67
- jQuery 1.9 (tried from 1.4 to 1.12 - no impact)
- php 5.6.40
- post_max_size=512M
- memory_limit=512M
- max_input_time=600

Tried adding additional caching via boost, decrease weight of module which contains saving hook - no impact. Please help.

Comment: What is `max_input_vars` set to? Try upping it

Comment: Yes, it helped, I increased from 1000 to 3000 and it worked, thanks a lot!